# Looking for image processing library for pure Ruby

Tags: ruby, image-processing

Most of the libraries/ codes I find are for RoR and not pure ruby. Even if I google pure ruby image upload, I get Pure Ruby On Rails ;)

So...I am looking for a gem/ library/ code that will do simply couple things:

- check if it's a valid image file
- resize image to the predefined values
- save it as jpg (from jpeg, jpg, png, gif, bmp)

Comment: Do you want something entirely written in ruby? If not, take a look at: rmagick, http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Comment: just to be used with pure ruby, not RoR

Comment: Then I hope that rmagick will suit your needs :) I haven't used it, but I have some experience with Graphics Magick and Image Magick, so I think that this may be very good option for you.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [mini magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) or [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick):

There are [others](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/image_processing).

Note you can use a gem outside of Ruby on Rails. In your command line do:

`$ gem install gem_name`

And in your ruby file, require it

`require 'gem_name'`

Comment: please forgive me for this stupid question, but what 'command line' please ... I am completely new to ruby ... thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

checkout https://github.com/jcupitt/ruby-vips a fast an awesome image processing library